# Constructing an array base on CURL response

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, curl

**Mac OS X (Shell)**

I'm trying to constructing an array base on the response of my curl.

**zsh**

```
readarray -t fontList < <(curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list)
for i in "${fontList[@]}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

I got this

```
➜  Desktop readarray -t fontList < <(curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list)                         
zsh: command not found: readarray                                                                        
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                          
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed                            
➜  Desktop for i in "${fontList[@]}"; do                                                                 
for>     echo $i                                                                                         
100  3428  100  3428    0     0  27206      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 26992                           
(23) Failed writing body
```

---

**bash**

```
bash-3.2$ readarray -t fontList < <(curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list)
bash: readarray: command not found
bash-3.2$ for i in "${fontList[@]}"; do
>     echo $i
> done  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3428  100  3428    0     0  24140      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 24140
(23) Failed writing body

bash-3.2$
```

I expected to get a list like this
http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list

Did I do sth wrong ?

Comment: Well, first of all, you're using zsh, not bash. And it doesn't have bash's readarray built-in.

Comment: I can change to bash shell and still the same.

Comment: `readarray: command not found` -- not if you're changing to bash 4.0 or later. (Note that MacOS comes with bash 3.2, but that's ancient -- current versions are in the 5.x series).

Comment: The ancient version of bash that comes with os x is too old to have it; readarray dates from bash 4.

Comment: Will updating bash caused a lot of trouble?

Comment: @cyb3rZ, you _can't_ replace `/usr/bin/bash` on current (Catalina or Big Sur) versions of MacOS (and if you could, it could cause trouble), but what you can do (and should do!) is just install a newer one at a different location; Nix, Macports and Homebrew (listed in order of my personal preference) can do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compatible with the ancient bash 3.2 shipped by Apple, and also with zsh:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  array+=( "$line" )
done < <(curl ...)
```

Comment: Compatible with bash 3.2 but not zsh:
`IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list)`

Comment: @LéaGris, consider adding a `&& printf '\0'` to the end of the process substitution there (which will have the happy effect of making `read`'s exit status indicate success only if `curl`'s does -- I sometimes use that pattern even in bash 4.x and later specifically for that side effect; particularly relevant if one adds `--fail` to the `curl` command).